# MySQL High Severity Error

Tags: mysql

I am completely new to MySQL. I am not a programmer or anything.

I was installing the program months ago, and forgot my root password, tried to fix things and it failed.

I did a system restore and now I get two messages.

One is short:

```
"Log file path must be defined before calling the WriteToLog method"
```

The second is long:

```
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbenchConnectionCollection.LoadXmlFile(Boolean saving)
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbenchConnectionCollection.Load()
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbench.LoadExternalConnections()
   at MySQL.Utility.Classes.MySQLWorkbench.MySqlWorkbench.set_ExternalApplicationConnectionsFilePath(String value)
   at MySql.Notifier.Notifier.InitializeMySqlWorkbenchStaticSettings()
   at MySql.Notifier.Notifier..ctor()
   at MySql.Notifier.NotifierApplicationContext..ctor()
   at MySql.Notifier.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Have I destroyed my MySQL, can I fix this myself? Or should I call someone?

Comment: When you say you performed a system restore, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I am referring to windows resetting to an earlier restore point.

Comment: Was the restore point before or after you installed MySQL?

Comment: It was after I installed MySQL. To be honest, I installed MySQL several months ago, and I think I've had a system restore about three times.

Comment: Then, if I were you, I'd uninstall everything to do with MySQL and start afresh with a new reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Decided to just remove and reinstall it!

Comment: I suspect this was the only way to go once your attempt to fix the original issue had damaged the installation - I guess the lesson is to get better advice first next time?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can use something like this:

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: B.5.4.1 How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: I did try this, but I did not have success, unfortuately.

Comment: I guess you did something wrong as this process used by many and it works for everyone...

Comment: I'm quite sure I did!

Comment: alexus perhaps it works for everyone who hasn't broken their install? I think this would have helped the OP before they tried to fix things